# Static or global 'var' type?

Tags: c#, xml, global-variables

I'm loading a bunch of objects from XML at the start of my main class, into a 'var', using LINQ. I am trying to implement the 'Strategy' pattern in my program though, and I need to reference the 'var' in these strategy classes.

Is there any way I can do this? My understanding is usually I would use static variables, but that doesn't seem to work for 'var'?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Below code loads the XML file and builds Product objects with LINQ

        XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load("inventory.xml");
        IEnumerable<Product> products = from q in XDoc.Descendants("product")
            select new Product
                {
                    RecordNumber = Convert.ToInt32(q.Element("recordNumber").Value),
                    Name = q.Element("name").Value,
                    Stock = Convert.ToInt32(q.Element("stock").Value),
                    Price = Convert.ToInt32(q.Element("price").Value),
                    CartQuantity = 0,
                    CartPrice = 0
                 };

        // Builds one instance of the cart that will be used to hold products

        Cart ShoppingCart = new Cart();

        Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO CONSOLE-BASED SHOPPING CART!");
        Start:
        Console.WriteLine("Following options are available: \n" +
        "1. Add an item to cart, \n" +
        "2. Remove an item from the cart, \n" +
        "3. View the cart \n" +
        "4. Checkout and Pay \n" +
        "5. Exit \n");
        String input = Console.ReadLine();

        Context context;
```

and the other classes:

```
     public class Cart : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    //Cart class - one instance is created to hold all the user's items
    //Includes methods to add, remove and check if cart contains an item
    // Also includes enumerator

    private List<Product> items;
    public Cart()
    {
        items = new List<Product>();
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return items[i];
        }
    }

    public void AddItem(Product prod)
    {
            items.Add(prod); 
    }

    public void RemoveProduct(Product prod)
    {
        items.Remove(prod);
    }

    public int CartCount()
    {
        return items.Count();
    }

    public void WriteToConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,16} {1, 16} {2, 16} {3, 16}","Item No.", "Item", "Amount", "Price");
        int TotalCost = 0;      //Iterator below allows us to work out total price
        foreach (Product x in this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,16} {1, 16} {2, 16} {3, 16}", x.RecordNumber, x.Name, x.CartQuantity, x.CartPrice);
            TotalCost = TotalCost + x.CartPrice;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Total Price: {0,54}", TotalCost);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        foreach (Product x in this)
        {
            this.RemoveProduct(x);
            x.CartQuantity = 0;
            x.CartPrice = 0;
        }
    }

     public class Product
{

    // Product class - objects are built using LINQ in main method

    public int RecordNumber { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public int CartQuantity { get; set; } 
    public int CartPrice { get; set; }

    public Product() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` is just a keyword that tells the compiler to infer the type of the variable.  It *does not* create a dynamically-typed variable, for example.

In the particular case you have shown here, the type of `products` will be `IEnumerable<Product>`.  So if you replace `var` with `IEnumerable<Product>` then you will see the same behavior.  (In fact, this is exactly what the compiler is doing -- if you look at the IL produced by the C# compiler, the local will have the type `IEnumerable<Product>`!)

C# forbids you to use `var` when declaring anything except a local.  If you are declaring a field, for example, you need to use an explicit type.  Which type you choose will depend on the particular data type that field needs to hold, so I can't provide an answer that will work for every case.  (In some cases you may want to use the type of the expression, in others maybe you want to use an interface type.)

Comment: okay thanks, so I can replace 'var' with 'IEnumerable<Product>' but I still can't declare that as static. If I want to be able to access this in other classes, what can I do?

Comment: @JordanAndrews Well, that depends on information I don't have about the design of your program.  You could possibly pass the object as a parameter to methods that need it, or declare a static variable somewhere of type `IEnumerable<Product>` (or, better yet, `IList<Product>`, and call `.ToList()` on your enumerable to turn it into a precomputed list).  I can't infer the correct approach from the limited amount of information in your question.

Comment: Basically I'm just creating a console 'shopping cart' application, so I read from this variable loaded as XML, make a heap of changes depending on what the user inputs, and then save the changes upon checking out. From a little bit of research it sounds like maybe a static class is a good idea, as its just this one instance of products from the XML file that I need to change. However I've been told not to use lots of static methods (which would inevitably happen if I have to make changes to the class, right?). How does passing it as a parameter work, is that through `ref`?

Comment: @JordanAndrews Again, I can't say if you should use `ref` without seeing the rest of the design.  If something is going to be changing data, generally rather than altering an existing structure I prefer to feed it data, let it work, and have it return a new structure with the new data.  I don't know how well that will work in your particular case though.

Comment: I've attached enough code so that you should be able to work out the jist of the program now. The main method has 4 more 'switch' parts. To be honest I know this is implemented shockingly, but it's for an assignment and I've been struggling so I just wanted to make sure I could at least get a working program so I can actually pass. Basically I've built a cart that I load with products selected from the XML file based on input. What I'm trying to do is put all of that switch "1" statement into the method of a new class, so as to create a new 'strategy', and id have more for the rest of theswitc

Comment: @JordanAndrews If you are intending to move this to your new strategy class, and if the strategy class has a reference back to the context, could you just store the list of products on the context?

Comment: Thanks for this! I am trying it now but can't seem to work out how to give the strategy a reference back to the context. At this stage, my context has a Strategy attribute but the Strategy class is basically empty. Do I give it a `ref Context _context` somehow?